# Getting ANR in WorkManger due to The "main" (tid=1) thread is in suspended state. This is likely due to garbage collection

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, android-workmanager

I have implemented the WorkManager version 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha06' . I am getting ANR mostly in Application onCreate with this message.

**The "main" (tid=1) thread is in suspended state. This is likely due to garbage collection.**

With the following code pointer

```
Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_SET flg=0x34000010 cmp=com.opentalk/androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver }
```

androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver

Mostly these ANR are shown in Third party SDK initialization. For example :

```
com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetUi.<init> (TweetUi.java)
```

com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter. (Twitter.java)

Please suggest how to handle this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The alpha06 is quite old. I suggest that you try your application with the latest release (alpha09) to see if the issue is still there.

Comment: Yes, I had upgraded to alpha08 where I had observed the same issue.I will update it to alpha09 and see if it gets resolved. Thanks